# How can I get the firestore server date for my angular application

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

My application need to get the firestore server date to grant user some authorization.

Currently I am using new Date() as below which gives the date of the local machine.

```
 today = new Date()
 if (Utils.getDayDiff(this.signupDate, today > 60 ) {
            // disable the feature
}
```

Utils.getDayDiff(..) is a function I have written to find the day difference between two Date objects.

Is there a way to initialize the above today variable with the firestore server date.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If by "firestore server date" you mean `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, no, that value is not immediately present in your client app.  There is not a simple way to get Firestore's sense of current time from its own servers.

The best you can do is write a document with that field value, then read the document back. By that time, the timestamp will be inaccurate by the amount of time it took to do those reads and writes, and it will not work if you're offline.

Also, it's not a good idea to use client code to grant secure access to special features. Client code can be compromised.  Any sort of security controls or restrictions should ultimately be enforced on the backend, which should always have an accurate sense of time, and can't be compromised.